# How to import a font-awesome icon inside an svg in angular?

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I can embed an font-awesome icon in angular. As described in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome.  This works.

**home.component.html**

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSkullCrossbones"></fa-icon>
```

Once I embed a font-awesome icon inside an svg, the icon doesn't appear. It does exist in the DOM. My code editor(VS-code) marks fa-icon in red.

**home.component.html**

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 1000 1000' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faSkullCrossbones"></fa-icon>
</svg>
```

**html output**

```
<svg _ngcontent-nwq-c23="" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <fa-icon _ngcontent-nwq-c23="" class="ng-fa-icon" style="color: white;" ng-reflect-icon="[object Object]">
    <svg role="img" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="skull-crossbones" class="svg-inline--fa fa-skull-crossbones fa-w-14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
        <path fill="currentColor" d="M439.15 453.06L297.17 384l141.99-69.06c7.9-3.95 11.11-13.56 7.15-21.46L432 264.85c-3.95-7.9-13.56-11.11-21.47-7.16L224 348.41 37.47 257.69c-7.9-3.95-17.51-.75-21.47 7.16L1.69 293.48c-3.95 7.9-.75 17.51 7.15 21.46L150.83 384 8.85 453.06c-7.9 3.95-11.11 13.56-7.15 21.47l14.31 28.63c3.95 7.9 13.56 11.11 21.47 7.15L224 419.59l186.53 90.72c7.9 3.95 17.51.75 21.47-7.15l14.31-28.63c3.95-7.91.74-17.52-7.16-21.47zM150 237.28l-5.48 25.87c-2.67 12.62 5.42 24.85 16.45 24.85h126.08c11.03 0 19.12-12.23 16.45-24.85l-5.5-25.87c41.78-22.41 70-62.75 70-109.28C368 57.31 303.53 0 224 0S80 57.31 80 128c0 46.53 28.22 86.87 70 109.28zM280 112c17.65 0 32 14.35 32 32s-14.35 32-32 32-32-14.35-32-32 14.35-32 32-32zm-112 0c17.65 0 32 14.35 32 32s-14.35 32-32 32-32-14.35-32-32 14.35-32 32-32z"></path>
    </svg>
  </fa-icon>
</svg>
```

How should I embed and see a font-awesome icon inside a svg?

Comment: Did you created a variable of faSkullCrossbones?

Comment: @MohammadDaliri Yes. Just like `faCoffee` in the referenced docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give the perfect answer as it depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

One approach is to avoid `fa-icon` component altogether and render the icon path manually as part of your own SVG object.

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 1000 1000' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path [attr.d]="faSkullCrossbones.icon[4]"></path>
</svg>
```

Another approach is to render `fa-icon` into SVG's [`symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) and then embed it with [`use`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use).

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSkullCrossbones" symbol="foobar"></fa-icon>

<svg viewBox='0 0 1000 1000' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use xlink:href="#foobar" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Nested SVG is valid markup https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/mimic-relative-positioning-in-svg/

Comment: @JHeth Ah, didn't know that! Thanks for the link. I've removed the incorrect statement from the answer.

Comment: Nice, this means I can use it in JS too ;)

Comment: On a sidenote based on the output in my question the viewBox should be ~`viewBox="0 0 448 512"`, otherwise you end up with an unexpectedly small image.

Comment: viewBox width and height are found in `faSkullCrossbones.icon[0]` and `faSkullCrossbones.icon[1]`